# convert this (algorithm?) to computer code

Tags: terminology

I am trying to learn something new, and this might be the wrong place for it.

I have this:
[image: Math thing]

and I have a few questions

1. What do you call this, an algorithm?
2. If I want to learn how to read it where should I start
3. how would this translate in to c#, would I be right in thinking k = Math.Log(m / n) * 2; ? (I know that in .net Math.Log is ln and Math.Log10 is log.)

EDIT
I am looking at Bloom Filters - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter - this is the equation for finding the optimal number of hashes to use.
K is the optimal number of hashes
M is the known number of bits in the array/filter
N is the known number of elements to be added to the filter

Comment: I'm new here. A comment on the down vote would be helpful.

Comment: An algorithm is a process where you follow a set of rules to get a result. This would be more of an equation. Edit: also what are $k,m,n$?

Comment: Obviously it is an equation (or assignment). And the log is applied to 2 not to $m/n.$

Comment: $k, m, n$ are variables (maybe all integers), and $k = \frac mn \ln 2$ is an equation stating that $k$ is equal to $m$ divided $n$ times  the natural logarithm of $2$.

Comment: In the cited Wiki article $k$ is an integer, where as simple coding would give a floating point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a formula or an equation rather than an algorithm - an algorithm would have multiple steps.

In C# I think you would write this as

k = (m/n)*Math.Log(2)

This assumes that you have values for $m$ and $n$ and want to assign a value to $k$.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you. Got to wait 5 minutes to except though!

Comment: Since k should be an integer, you should add a ceil.